# The provided role does not have sufficient permissions to access CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am implementing CodePipeline; using GitHub, CodeBuild and Amazon ECS (blue/green). The role I am using, is the one generated by the Pipeline: ecsTaskExecutionRole

When generated, it is equipped with the following **policies**:
*AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy* (containing the following actions):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]}
```

And the following **Trust relationships**:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codebuild.amazonaws.com",
          "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Given that the role is auto-generated, one would assume that either it would have ALL the necessary permissions (for the pipeline to function) OR AWS would have a guide on which permissions to assign (to either a policy OR the trust relationship configuration).

Despite, updating the trust relationship to include:

```
"Service": [
      "codebuild.amazonaws.com",
      "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
      "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
      "codepipeline.amazonaws.com",
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ]
```

I still get the error: 
[image]

I have seen this issue raised in multiple blogs/forum, spanning the past 1-2 years; it's incredible that this is still not properly documented as part of the AWS tutorials (or relative blogs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### "The provided role does not have sufficient permissions to access CodeDeploy"

This error suggests the CodePipeline role is missing "codedeploy:" related permissions.

Can you please add

```
codedeploy:*
```

to the role and try again.

If you do not want to add all CodeDeploy permissions, you will need to investigate 'AccessDenied' calls in Cloudtrail and allow just those. Usually these are the required ones:

```
{
      "Action": [
        "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
        "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision",
        "codedeploy:GetApplication",
        "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
        "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
        "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

The default "CodePipeline Service Role Policy" is documented here:

[1] Manage the CodePipeline Service Role - Review the Default CodePipeline Service Role Policy  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/how-to-custom-role.html#view-default-service-role-policy

Comment: Thanks, I solved this, then discovered several other issues beyond. Green tick for making the effort to answer, much appreciated.